# Find trashed file location in GIO

Tags: c, gio, recycle-bin

The documentation says that all files moved to trash are stored normally in `~/.local/share/Trash/files`. Are there an exception for files removed from removable media? Are they stored in `drive_root/.Trash-xxx` directory? Or is this behavior obsolete?

How do I find real file path of file in trash can? I have a list of `GFileInfo` obtained from `g_file_enumerate_children` for `trash:///` uri. It's easy if all files are stored in one directory. But I'm afraid this could be different for removable drives.

Answer (score 1):

From removeable media there are the .Trash-$(user_id) folders, so you will have to get all mounted disks as well as the home trashcan.

Under each mounted device (not being the home folder) will be a .Trash folder for each user ever having something deleted. So e.g. for my user `foo` which has ID 1000 (see `/etc/passwd`) you will have to look for `.Trash-1000` folders.

This is AFAIK not obsolete, just think about the oposite, the file would have to be copied over to your home storage just to move it to trash...

For the second part, you probably better off asking that on the glib/gtk mailinglist.

Comment: Can you provide some link to the documentation that describe these possible locations of trash folder? I thought it's obsolete because it  isn't mentioned in the GIO documentation.

Comment: Did not read it througly, just had a glance but should contain all you need http://www.ramendik.ru/docs/trashspec.html